# stack install codecov-haskell failed with error

Tags: shell, haskell, haskell-stack, codecov

I am trying to install [codecov-haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codecov-haskell) via [stack](/questions/tagged/stack) using `stack install codecov-haskell -v`, I've got the following error:

```
2019-10-07 19:31:22.039891: [info] codecov-haskell> build
2019-10-07 19:31:22.040092: [debug] Run process within /tmp/stack30689/codecov-haskell-0.5.0/: /home/mkultra/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
2019-10-07 19:31:22.129625: [info] codecov-haskell> Preprocessing library for codecov-haskell-0.5.0..
2019-10-07 19:31:22.129758: [info] codecov-haskell> Building library for codecov-haskell-0.5.0..
2019-10-07 19:31:22.264569: [warn] codecov-haskell> 
2019-10-07 19:31:22.264773: [warn] codecov-haskell> <no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
2019-10-07 19:31:22.264869: [warn] codecov-haskell>     These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
2019-10-07 19:31:22.264938: [warn] codecov-haskell>         Paths_codecov_haskell
2019-10-07 19:31:22.265078: [info] codecov-haskell> [1 of 9] Compiling Paths_codecov_haskell
2019-10-07 19:31:22.494452: [info] codecov-haskell> [2 of 9] Compiling Trace.Hpc.Codecov.Config
2019-10-07 19:31:22.534420: [info] codecov-haskell> [3 of 9] Compiling Trace.Hpc.Codecov.Paths
2019-10-07 19:31:22.714734: [info] codecov-haskell> [4 of 9] Compiling CodecovHaskellCmdLine
2019-10-07 19:31:24.097299: [info] codecov-haskell> [5 of 9] Compiling Trace.Hpc.Codecov.Types
2019-10-07 19:31:24.245865: [info] codecov-haskell> [6 of 9] Compiling Trace.Hpc.Codecov.Curl
2019-10-07 19:31:25.632324: [warn] codecov-haskell> 
2019-10-07 19:31:25.632698: [warn] codecov-haskell> /tmp/stack30689/codecov-haskell-0.5.0/src/Trace/Hpc/Codecov/Curl.hs:55:20: error:
2019-10-07 19:31:25.632804: [warn] codecov-haskell>     • Couldn't match type ‘IO (Maybe a)’
2019-10-07 19:31:25.632879: [warn] codecov-haskell>                      with ‘RetryStatus -> IO (Maybe a)’
2019-10-07 19:31:25.632955: [warn] codecov-haskell>       Expected type: IO (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe a)
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633025: [warn] codecov-haskell>         Actual type: (RetryStatus -> IO (Maybe a)) -> IO (Maybe a)
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633090: [warn] codecov-haskell>     • In the expression: retrying expRetryPolicy isNothingM
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633165: [warn] codecov-haskell>       In an equation for ‘performWithRetry’:
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633236: [warn] codecov-haskell>           performWithRetry
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633310: [warn] codecov-haskell>             = retrying expRetryPolicy isNothingM
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633382: [warn] codecov-haskell>             where
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633464: [warn] codecov-haskell>                 isNothingM _ = return . isNothing
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633537: [warn] codecov-haskell>     • Relevant bindings include
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633610: [warn] codecov-haskell>         performWithRetry :: IO (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe a)
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633685: [warn] codecov-haskell>           (bound at src/Trace/Hpc/Codecov/Curl.hs:55:1)
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633758: [warn] codecov-haskell>    |
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633831: [warn] codecov-haskell> 55 | performWithRetry = retrying expRetryPolicy isNothingM
2019-10-07 19:31:25.633905: [warn] codecov-haskell>    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2019-10-07 19:31:25.703733: [warn] codecov-haskell> 
2019-10-07 19:31:25.703992: [info] Completed 2 action(s).
2019-10-07 19:31:25.794909: [error] 
--  While building package codecov-haskell-0.5.0 using:
      /home/mkultra/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I had a similar error using `cabal install codecov-haskell` and the same error on CI using `stack install codecov-haskell`.
Previously I had a [problem with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259602/stack-install-curl-fails) during codecov-haskell installation on my local machine. On CI didn't have any problem with it.

Any suggestion?

```
Stack version: 2.1.3
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/guillaume-nargeot/codecov-haskell/issues/13) and [merge request](https://github.com/guillaume-nargeot/codecov-haskell/pull/14) ready to be merged from Jul 26, 2017, for it.

Looks like the author doesn't support this project anymore.

Comment: I have dropped him an email, asking about the current project status.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by doing something like this in cabal and stack:

```
resolver: lts-13.25
extra-deps:
  - github: guillaume-nargeot/codecov-haskell
    commit: 8448801f8d01624e4cd60420beb3fdc85c099576
packages:
  - .
```

You basically anchor a specific commit from github as your dependency that actually compiles!